# Alter column in table to auto increment in Sybase ASE 16.0

Tags: auto-increment, sap-ase, alter

I am using Sybase ASE16.0 database in which I am trying to alter a column in an existing USER table so that it autoincrements every time a row is added to the table. The column: user_id is set as primary key and not null.

I have gone through many sybase tutorials and have tried many approaches but of no avail. Here are some queries that I wrote to make this change:

```
ALTER TABLE USER (user_id smallint IDENTITY not null)
ALTER TABLE USER ALTER user_id smallint IDENTITY not null
ALTER TABLE USER MODIFY user_id smallint NOT NULL IDENTITY
ALTER TABLE USER MODIFY user_id smallint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
ALTER TABLE USER MODIFY user_id smallint NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT
ALTER TABLE USER ALTER user_id smallint NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT
ALTER TABLE USER user_id smallint AUTOINCREMENT
```

I expect a SYBASE DB compliant query that would alter the user_id column in the table to autoincrement it by 1 on adding a new record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

*Adds an IDENTITY column to a table. For each existing row in the table, Adaptive Server assigns a unique, sequential column value. The IDENTITY column could be type numeric or integer, and a scale of zero. The precision determines the maximum value (10 5 -1, or 99,999) that can be inserted into the column:*

`alter table sales_daily
add ord_num numeric (5,0) identity`

Found [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X68185.htm)